# Download and sort data from JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, sorting, tvos

I have two JSON files with data:

1 - categories (id and name);
2 - objects (id, name and category's id).

Earlier I needed only objects, but now I need to sort it by categories. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should better describe your problem. For example, include a sample of the JSON and add code where you show how you attempted to solve  the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_name = array_name.sort
{
($0["category_id"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1["category_id"] as! String) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Try this code. 
`array_name` is `NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "category_id", ascending: true)
    var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

you must pass an array of sort descriptors (even if it's only one)